# GLMM Results depending on chosen variable?

Tags: r, lme4

I am experiencing a problem with the GLMM in one of the datasets I created.

**My Example:** 3 Individuals go through a door and need to decide to either go to a "circle" or a "triangle" that is displayed on a wall in the next room. They are shown either on the left or right side and their appearance on the sides is randomized. (Never "circle" and "triangle" on the same side). There is a reward when going to the circle and but in general it can be seen as a 50/50 chance.  All individuals are tested 20 times.

Individual 1: is 20x correct

Individual 2: is 20x correct

Individual 3: is  0x correct

I am trying to see with GLMM whether the individuals as a group were able to significantly choose the "circle" over the "triangle". However the Pr(>|z|) changes depending on which variable I chose to be noted in my datasheet when an individual chose correct.

**My Formula:** `glmer(Response~1 + (1 |Individual), family = binomial, data=x)`

`1 = "correct choice" ; 0 = "wrong choice"  -> Pr(>|z|) = 0.0172`

[image]

`0 = "correct choice" ; 1 = "wrong choice"  -> Pr(>|z|) = 0.0369`

[image]

How is it possible that my outcome changes depending on how I note down the results? In my understanding there should be any difference.

Comment: "However the Pr(>|z|) changes depending on which variable I chose to be noted in my datasheet when an individual chose correct." What does that mean? You are only showing one formula, and no information about this.

Comment: I am reffering to the way how "correct"  and "wrong" choices are noted. Either "0" & "1" or "1" & "0". The Pr(>|z|) changes depending on this choice. In general the outcome should not change, depending what I chose to use as a representation of "correct" and "wrong"

Comment: That indeed would be the logical thought. However, GLMM models are fitted using laplace approximation for the log-likelihood. For more exact p-values (that will be unaffected) bootstrapping or other simulation approaches are better and recommended.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot! I have a look at it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.